# File for static list of possible objects?

Tags: c++, file-io, data-structures

I'm getting into game dev and want to know how to save a list of objects to a file.

Let me clarify: I'm trying to make a console dungeon builder and am trying to make a file where I can save all possible tile types.  Each type would include the tile's name and its exit directions.  A similar process would be used to store a list of rooms in a text adventure.

My plan was to store this data in a text file and then read each entry into a vector of structs during runtime.

However, I'm having trouble thinking of a good, non-tedious way to do this and I can't research it because **I don't know what this sort of thing is called**.

Any light shed on the matter would really help.  If I wasn't clear enough anywhere I'l try to clarify as best I can.

Comment: You want to research for deserialization.

Comment: just look for write and read from files c++

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html